# macos terminal base64: /dev/urandom

Tags: macos

The following use to work in macos terminal

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 100000 > file.txt

base64: invalid argument /dev/urandom
Usage:  base64 [-hDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

Comment: Sounds like a topic for apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: base64 reads from stdin by default, as the man page shows. Use `-i`

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my side:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=100000 | base64 > file.txt
```

UPD:

The `base64` util is not standardized across different Unix-like operating systems, and base64 included with macOS does not accept a file path as an argument directly, read more:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/base64-invocation.html for most linux systems
- https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=base64&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports for BSD systems, including macos